# to get the unique name by using starting letter of a string and concatenate with an integer

Tags: java

I need to get the unique name from a string and concatenate with an integer in java.So I want to take first letter of the string and increment that letter with an integer.
Example: tenant name: 
 "ani,raj,rob" and i need to get the
 schema name like a001,r001,r002
here r value will be incremented because of repetition.So I request you to help me find answer for this.I am getting the first letter from a string but I need to concatenate that with an integer.

```
String name = new String(tenantName); 
char sc=tenantName.charAt(0); 
String whereClause="tenant_id= select max(tenant_id) from tenant_connection_details 
                                        tcd1 where schema_name like'"+sc+"%'"; 
tenantList= tenantImpl.getAllTenantsByWhereClause(whereClause);
```

Comment: Your aim is not clear (or I could not understand). As I understand, you can get the first letter. Is your problem about concatenation or generating an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> myNames = new ArrayList<String>();
myNames.add("ani");
myNames.add("raj");
myNames.add("rob");
myNames.add("jigar");

int counter=1;
for(String str:myNames){
System.out.println(str.charAt(0)+String.format("%04d", i));
counter++;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for showing interest in answering my question

Comment: @yopirates So finally you got your problem solved ? if so you can mark the answer which helped most

Comment: actually I m not getting my value incremented. Its taking a0001 for adam and also a0001 for albert .Its not getting incremented.Can you just help me out in this

Comment: String name = new String(tenantName); 
char sc=tenantName.charAt(0); 
String whereClause="tenant_id= select max(tenant_id) from tenant_connection_details 
                                        tcd1 where schema_name like'"+sc+"%'"; 
tenantList= tenantImpl.getAllTenantsByWhereClause(whereClause);

Comment: @yopirates You can think over it now.

Comment: @yopirates So finally you got your problem solved ? if so you can mark the answer which helped most

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```
char sc=tenantName.charAt(0); // May use Character.toLowerCase() here, if only lowercase letters are allowed
String whereClause="tenant_id= select max(tenant_id) from tenant_connection_details 
                                    tcd1 where schema_name like'"+sc+"%'"; 
tenantList= tenantImpl.getAllTenantsByWhereClause(whereClause);
int number = tenentList.size() + 1;
String result = Character.toString(sc) + String.format("%04d", number);
```

Comment: [CODE]String name = new String(tenantName);
                char sc=tenantName.charAt(0);
                String whereClause="tenant_id= select max(tenant_id) from tenant_connection_details tcd1  where schema_name like'"+sc+"%'";
                 tenantList= tenantImpl.getAllTenantsByWhereClause(whereClause);[/CODE]

Comment: Thank you so much guys for showing interest in answering my question

Comment: your code is working but its not getting incremented if a give the name having same starting letter like if i give adam it takes as a0001 and if i give albert it should take as a0002 but its not taking

Comment: Hm, I supposed, this name is then added to database - so next iteration of this code will have tenentList.size() increased by 1.

Comment: yes it is added to database and I m using pgsql.I m using this in my servlet

Comment: Then when we add adam, tenentList.size() will return 0, number will be set to 1, and result will be "a0001". When we add albert, tenentList.size() will return 1 ("adam" resocr is found), number will be set to 2, and result will be "a0001", and so on. Or I misunderstood question / comments :)

Comment: actually i need to increment the next taking value to a0002.okay let me give you an example i took adam first it gave a0001 and then i took robert it gave r0001 later i gave albert it should have take a0002 because a0001 would have assigned to adam.The string a0001 is actually unique so it should not get repeated.so it should take it as a0002 and if i give Adolf for the next one then it should take it as a0003.Hope you got it now.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, it should be something like this (not safe or checked or anything!!):

```
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void strangeConcat(String name){
    int index = 1;

    while(this.list.contains(String.valueOf(name.charAt(0)) 
            + this.getThreeDigitIndex(index))){
        index++;
    }

    this.list.add(String.valueOf(name.charAt(0)) + this.getThreeDigitIndex(index));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for showing interest in answering my question